# How can i run code behind method from keybinding on Ext.Net V2.1

Tags: code-behind, ext.net

This code is in my GridPanel.

```
<ext:KeyMap runat="server">
    <Binding>
        <ext:KeyBinding>
        <Keys>
            <ext:Key Code="ENTER" />
        </Keys>
        </ext:KeyBinding>
    </Binding>
</ext:KeyMap>
```

How can i run code behind when press enter.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<ext:KeyMap runat="server" Target="={Ext.isGecko ? Ext.getDoc() : Ext.getBody()}">
    <Binding>
        <ext:KeyBinding DefaultEventAction="StopEvent" Handler="alert('ENTER');">
            <Keys>
                <ext:Key Code="ENTER" />
            </Keys>
        </ext:KeyBinding>
    </Binding>        
</ext:KeyMap>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've fixed the example